# Intermediate value property with no continuity

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

**Definition**: A real function f has the *intermediate value property* on an interval I containing [a,b] if f(a) < v < f(b) or f(b) < v < f(a); that is, if v is between f(a) and f(b), there is between a and b a c ∈ [a,b] such that f(c) = v.

What is an example function that has this property, and how do I prove that a strictly increasing function f:[a,b]→ R which has this property is continuous on [a,b]?

Comment: Such functions are sometimes called [Darboux functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_function).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you wanted an example of a *discontinuous* function satisfying IVP. If $f$ is differentiable then the Mean Value Theorem shows that $f'$ has IVP, although $f'$ need not be continuous.

Comment: would f(x) = 2 if x less or equal to 1 or x if x is greater than 1 work? @David C. Ulrich

Comment: @Leaf: Your function doesn't work. For example, for $x$ between $0$ and $1.1,$ the value of $f(x)$ is between $1$ and $2,$ but omits all values (strictly) between $1.1$ and $2.$ A function that works is $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ with $f(0)=0.$

Comment: Ahh.. I see, any clues as how to prove the continuous property though? @Dave L. Renfro

Comment: @Leaf: Do you know that any discontinuity of a monotone function must be a jump discontinuity? What you want follows immediately from this fact, because no function with a jump discontinuity can satisfy the intermediate value property (the example you gave in your first comment illustrates this).

Answer (score -1):

An example is the identity.

Hint (for $f$ increasing): $f$ must be surjective in $[a,b]$ for all $[a,b]\subset I$

Comment: What do you mean by the identity? @vvnitram

Comment: @Leaf f(x)=x is the identity

Comment: isn't that continuous? @vvnitram

Comment: @Leaf with an apropiate distance, no